# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'insert'

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-parse-error

I am new to php. I am trying to connect android with phpmyadmin using webservice .

**php Code**

```
<?php
    include_once('configuration.php');


$UserId = $_POST['UserId'];
$ProductId = $_POST['ProductId'];
$DesiredQuantity = $_POST['DesiredQuantity'];
$cartstable=mysql_query("SELECT `UserId`, `ProductId`, `DesiredQuantity` FROM `carts` WHERE UId='".$UserId. "' AND ProductId='".$ProductId. "'");

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($cartstable);
        if($num_rows>0){
 $updateqry=mysql_query("Update `carts` set `DesiredQuantity`= `DesiredQuantity` + $DesiredQuantity) WHERE UId='".$UserId. "' AND ProductId='".$ProductId. "');

}
       else
{
$insertqry=mysql_query ("Insert into `carts` (`UId`, `ProductId`, `DesiredQuantity`) VALUES ('".$UserId. "','".$ProductId. "',$DesiredQuantity)");

}


        $carts_ful=mysql_query("SELECT `UserId`, `ProductId`, `DesiredQuantity` FROM `CARTS` WHERE UId='".$UserId. "'");

       while($carts = mysql_fetch_array($carts_ful)){
        extract($carts);
        $result[] = array("UserId" => $UserId,"ProductId" => $ProductId,"DesiredQuantity" => $DesiredQuantity); 
    }
        $json = array("Updated Cart Details" => $result);
       @mysql_close($conn); 
        header('Content-type: application/json');
       // echo "Selected Product is added to the Cart !";
        echo json_encode($json);


 ?>
```

When I tried running,I see the following error

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'insert' .
```

If I Cut and paste,

```
 $insertqry=mysql_query ("Insert into `carts` (`UId`, `ProductId`, `DesiredQuantity`) VALUES ('".$UserId. "','".$ProductId. "',$DesiredQuantity)");
```

line above the if statement ,It works fine.

I could not understand where is the problem .Please help me finding the solution .

Comment: You don't close the string at the end of the `$updateqry=mysql_query` line.

Comment: Use a proper editor/IDE. The syntax highlighting would have indicated the error, just as SO is doing. (I hate to think *which* editor people who ask these questions use..)

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) Now works fine @ Jon Stirling

Comment: Also, you have serious SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code. The `UPDATE` statement can be misused by a malicious user to set any column in any/all rows as they wish. Use parameter binding to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting should have been enough to spot the error.

You have missed a closing quote from one of your SQL queries. Find the amendment below.

```
 $updateqry=mysql_query("Update `carts` set `DesiredQuantity`= `DesiredQuantity` + $DesiredQuantity) WHERE UId='".$UserId. "' AND ProductId='".$ProductId."'");

}
       else
{
$insertqry=mysql_query ("Insert into `carts` (`UId`, `ProductId`, `DesiredQuantity`) VALUES ('".$UserId. "','".$ProductId. "',$DesiredQuantity)");

}
```